# kube-prometheus-stack: How to persist custom Grafana alert?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I've deployed the kube-prometheus-stack to our Azure Kubernetes Service.
We need a custom alert to signal Microsoft Teams when a pod has been evicted.
The steps, below, created our alert and it worked properly for a few days.
Suddenly, the custom alert has disappeared and the three new users for Grafana are gone.

So, how can I persist in Grafana the following items for the kube-prometheus-stack?

- A new notification channel set to a specific incoming webhook uri;
- A new custom alert rule;
- A few user accounts;

=================================================

HERE IS WHAT I DID AND IT WORKED PROPERLY UNTIL THE CHANGES WERE LOST:
* In Teams, I created a Connector and obtained my Incoming WebHook URI.

```
* In Grafana, I created a notification channel for Microsoft Teams and set the Incoming WebHook URI.  When I click the Send Test button, an alert appears in my channel in Teams, so it worked properly.

* In Grafana, I created a new Alert rule, which detects ejected/failed pods.  When I evicted a pod, the Alert fired and was posted in Microsoft Teams.

* In Grafana, I created a few user accounts for securing access to it.
```

=================================================

I need to figure out what changes are required for the Helm chart that deploys kube-prometheus-stack and what changes need to be made to our Kubernetes (secrets, configmap, PVC).

I'd really appreciate your guidance and I am sure that this question will benefit others.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Please improve the question and add the values file you are using

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Similar problem.